# How to use OkHTTP (on android) to store primitive data types on MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sql-server, okhttp

**What I want to do:**
Store 8 Strings and 2 doubles as a single row in a database hosted on a local machine (eventually I would like to move this online, I'm just using a local mysql for testing purposes).

---

I implemented OkHTTP:

```
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();

request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();
```

and have:

```
String postMessage = "{ \"mIDNumber\": \""+mIDNumber+
   "\n \", \"mType\": \""+mType+
   "\n \", \"mAddress\": \""+mAddress+
   "\n \", \"mOwner\": \""+mOwner+
   "\n \", \"mContactName\": \""+mContactName+
   "\n \", \"mContactNumber\": \""+mContactNumber+
   "\n \", \"mComments\": \""+mComments+"\" }";
```

as what I want to send to the server

My post method is:

```
String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
        Log.v("JSON:",json);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }
```

and the url I'm sending to is my desktop (http://192.168.0.100:3306)

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong because when I try to post I am recieving a protocol exception "Unexpected status line: N������" (yes, with those wierd ? symbols).

Also, do I need a PHP page to feed this data through? Can I just feed it to the mySQL server directly?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: no you can't write data to your remote db from your app directly

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look into Retrofit(http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) or Volley (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800) both these tools has easy to use JSON parsers.

Its really easy to make use of OkHTTP in Retrofit.

I prefer Retrofit as it is a bit slimmer to use.